# Sideload add-in for Outlook 2016

Tags: outlook-web-addins, office-store

I have tested my add in Outlook Web access but to complete the testing I need to sideload my add in to the Outlook 2016 client.

The only information I can find on this is located here and is out of date as I cannot get to the store from my latest version of Outlook

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/sideload-outlook-add-ins-for-testing

Please can someone help me find some up to date documentation on this or just explain how I can load the add-in into Outlook 2016?

Answer (score 2):

This documentation is current.

1. On the Home tab in Outlook 2016, select 'Get Add-ins'.
2. On the next screen select 'My add-ins' on the left hand side
3. Scroll down to 'Custom add-ins'
4. Click on 'Add a custom add-in'
   [image]

Comment: I have managed to get the "Get Add-Ins" button to show up now, however the button is greyed out so I cannot click on it. What do I need to do to be able to use the button?

Comment: What version of Outlook are you using? (You can get this from File > Office Account)
What type of account are you using? (Personal or School/Workplace)

Comment: The version of Outlook I have is Microsoft Outlook for Office 365 MS) and I am using it on a workplace email

Comment: Did you check this ("Specify the administrators and users who can install and manage add-ins for Outlook"): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/clients-and-mobile-in-exchange-online/add-ins-for-outlook/specify-who-can-install-and-manage-add-ins

Comment: As you are on a School/Workplace account, if this option is greyed out for you, you'll need to speak to your Organizations administrator, as this is an organization level setting.